# Find the probability to draw a specific amount of unique balls out of a ball pit by drawing $n\leq N$ balls

Tags: probability

I've come across a problem and despite not being able to find something to my aid, I've decided to post it as a question.

We have $N=57$ balls in a ball pit, 20 of which are red, and 37 of which are black. We can draw any number $57\geq n\geq 20$ of balls out of the ball pit.

Find the probability $p_n$ that all balls out of $n$ are **all** red.

For example, if we draw 22 balls, what's the probability that we have all 20 red balls? What if we draw 31 or 43?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The probability of picking a red ball is 20/57 (the frequency of red balls among the whole) and the probability of picking a black ball is 37/57. The probability of picking either a red or black ball is then 20/57+37/57=1, which we expect to be the case. This is the case for when all drawn balls are put back into the container. For the case when they are not, the probability changes with every draw, thus every later event (drawing red or drawing black ball) is dependent of what happened earlier. https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/probability-without-replacement.html (read!)

Answer (score 2):

There are ${57\choose n}$ ways to draw $n$ balls.  If $20$ are red, the other $n-20$ are black and are drawn from the $37$ black balls.  There are ${37\choose n-20}$ ways that this can occur.  The probability is  $${{37\choose n-20}\over{57\choose n}}$$